# How can i add custom behavior using pure ECS (Entity Component System) in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

We are currently making our dream game with thousands fast dying zombies.
Problem is - we are making it for mobile devices.

Hybrid ECS is not enough, cuz even 100-200 low poly zombies is to heavy for render even after ultimate optimization.

Solution is use only pure ECS. Followed this [tutorial](https://unity3d.college/2018/05/16/getting-started-unity-ecs/) i can spawn now 2-3k zombies on 40-50fps on low end devices.

But, im stuck on adding behavior. I just cant add it on each entity. By getting this tutorial as example - how to add custom behavior like AI scripts/systems for each cube?

I tried to add "system" on it, but it applies only on GameObject that u use for getting copy's.

P.S. I dont want to use external ECS frameworks, cuz im sure in future Unity built-in ECS will be the ultimate "from box" solution.

Answer (score 0):

You don't. With Unity ECS you register systems. Systems work on entities that have certain components attached. E.g. you can create a system that processes all Zombies (e.g. all entities with a "Zombie" component) and execute some logic for them in each tick. The trick with ECS is that you do not handle each entity separately but you run logic for all entities that share certain criteria. This is why it is so fast, but it requires to let go of the Monobehaviour approach, mentally. I found this tutorial helpful in getting some start of actually implementing logic: http://infalliblecode.com/unity-ecs-survival-shooter-part-1/

It's not 100% up-to-date but it should be enough to get you an idea how things roll with ECS.